# How do I programmatically (in vbscript) change/set the tcp port for a site under IIS?

Tags: iis, vbscript

My programming environment includes scripts for setting up my autobuild on a clean machine.

One step uses a vbscript to configure a website on IIS that is used to monitor the build.

On a particular machine I will be running apache on port 80 for a separate task.

I would like my vbscript to set the port to 8080 for the new site that it is adding.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `adsutil.vbs`, part of the IIS admin scripts, to change that:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/1/ServerBindings “:8080:”
```

In a default layout, the script resides in `C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\`.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to add a host header using WMI or ADSI

http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2006/07/28/188.aspx

An extract of the code on there (with a little editing)

```
    Dim objWebApp
    Dim intArraySize
    Dim arrOldBindings
    Dim arrNewBindings
```

```
Set objWebApp = GetObject("IIS://localhost/w3svc/" WebSiteID)

If isArray(objWebApp.ServerBindings) then

arrOldBindings = objWebApp.ServerBindings
    intArraySize = UBound(arrOldBindings)
    Redim arrNewBindings(intArraySize + 1)

    For i = 0 to intArraySize
    arrNewBindings(i) = arrOldBindings(i)
    Next

arrNewBindings(intArraySize + 1) = ":mydomain.com:8080:"

    objWebApp.Put "ServerBindings", (arrNewBindings)
    objWebApp.SetInfo

End If
```

Comment: IIS will assign an ID to the site when it is created (depending on version either random, or based on it's name). It's the same number used for the log file directory.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful - i think the example has a few +1 errors but gave me the general idea

Comment: could you point them out, and I'll clean up the answer (for others if they reference).

Comment: Ok i got it to work with the following changes: [line6]Set objWebApp = GetObject("IIS://localhost/w3svc/1") [line12]    Redim arrNewBindings(intArraySize) [line18] arrNewBindings(intArraySize) = ":mydomain.com:8080:" - I don't know vbscript so i might be misunderstanding